# get a key HEX from wpa/wpa2 handshake

Tags: encryption, wpa2

Can I get a key HEX from wpa/wpa2 handshake, or from the network in another way without knowing the passphrase?

Example:

Network SSID: linksys54gh WPA passphrase: radiustest

Hexadecimal key: 9e9988bde2cba74395c0289ffda07bc41ffa889a3309237a2240c934bcdc7ddb